# Avoid matching (λx.x)

Tags: isabelle, unification

Consider the theory

```
theory Scratch imports Main
begin

notepad
begin
  fix P and f g h :: "int ⇒ int"
  assume prems: "P f" "P g" "P h"
  assume comp: "⋀ f g. P f ⟹ P g ⟹ P (λ x. f (g x))"

  have "P (λ x. f (g (h x)))"
    sorry
end
end
```

Clearly the lemma can be shown from `prems` and `comp`. In fact, at first glance, one would expect that it can be shown by

```
by (intro prems comp)
```

but this just loops. The reason is that one possible unification of `comp` with the goal is `f = (λa. a)` and `g = (λ x. f (g (h x)))` (as can be seen by using `apply (rule comp)`) and no progress is made.

I understand that this is valid behaviour of `rule` reps. `intro`. Nevertheless from a pragmatic point of view I often come across simplification or introduction rules that would be very helpful in all cases where they match *except* when they match `(λx. x)`.

Is there any way to state `comp` so that Isabelle’s matcher will *not* consider a solution where `f` or `g` is `(λx. x)`?

If not, what are the technical and/or theoretical reasons why this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous examples in the Isabelle library of properties closed under function composition, e.g., continuity in HOLCF and Multivariate-Analysis. They all have a general composition rule like `comp`, but `comp` is never used in rule applications precisely because of the match with `%x. x`. Instead, only specialised instances are used, which you can obtain with the `THEN` attribute. In your example, this might look as follows:

```
have "P (%x. f (g (h x)))"
  by(rule prems prems[THEN comp])+
```

If you are looking just for a single method expression to prove this, you can exploit that `,` backtracks, i.e.,

```
have "P (%x. f (g (h x)))"
  by(rule prems|rule comp, rule prems)+
```

Alternatively, you could write your own wrapper of `rule` or `intros` that discards the head of the sequence of results.

```
have "P (%x. f (g (h x)))"
  apply(tactic {*
    REPEAT_FIRST (resolve_tac @{thms prems} ORELSE' 
                  (fn i => snd o Seq.chop 1 o resolve_tac @{thms comp} i))
  *})
```

Comment: Continuity in HOLCF is of course my motivating example. But if there are numerous examples, then my second question becomes even more relevant: Why can’t we have a way to not match `λx. x`?

Alternatively (and maybe more hackish), why can’t `rule` backtrack if the first result has the goal unmodified among the premises.